# jQuery find() & each() on dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a `<div>` element that contains multiple other `<div>`'s that are populated dynamically using jQuery/Ajax, I'm trying to run the following code but `find()` fails to get any of them.

Here's my HTML boilerplate prior to my data being populated.

```
<input type="text" id="inv-filter" class="form-control">
<div class="row itemList" style="margin-right: -2px;margin-left:-2px;">

</div>
```

And here's what it looks like after population.

```
<input type="text" id="inv-filter" class="form-control">
<div class="row itemList" style="margin-right: -2px;margin-left:-2px;">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2 shop-item" data-hash="Item Name 1">

    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2 shop-item" data-hash="Item Name 2">

    </div>
    ......
</div>
```

My Javascript looks like the following:

```
$('#inv-filter').keyup(function() {
    var search = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    var $sellContainer = $('.itemList');
    if (search.trim() === '') {
        $sellContainer.find('.shop-item').show();
        $sellContainer.find('.shop-item.selected').hide();
        return;
    }
    $sellContainer.find('.sell-item').each(function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('selected') && $(this).data('hash').text().toLowerCase().includes(search)) {
            $(this).show();
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

I've ran multiple tests inside console debugger such as `$('.itemList').length()` etc.. but doesn't appear to find any results & when entering text into my input field, nothing is happening

Comment: Can you turn your code into a working snippet, or create a fiddle? It will help people address your problem quickly.

Comment: `sell-item` or `shop-item`

Comment: Also `$(this).data('hash').toLowerCase()`, not `$(this).data('hash').text().toLowerCase()` - `data('hash')` return a string which does not have the `text()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sellContainer.find('.sell-item').each(function() { //replace sell-item with shop-item
        if (!$(this).hasClass('selected') && $(this).data('hash').text().toLowerCase().includes(search)) {
            $(this).show();
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
```